# Logstash API configuration http

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Im trying to create an API connection in Logstash and push the data to elasticsearch.
Both Elasticsearch and Logstash versions are 7.1.0.
Below id the logstash file:

```
input {
          http_poller {
            urls => {
              test2 => {
                method => get
        user => "readonly"
            password => "mypass@123"
                url => "https://nfr.saas.appdynamics.com/controller/rest/applications?output=JSON
                headers => {
                  Accept => "application/json"
                }
             }
            }
            request_timeout => 60
            # Supports "cron", "every", "at" and "in" schedules by rufus scheduler
            schedule => { cron => "* * * * * UTC"}
            codec => "json"
            # A hash of request metadata info (timing, response headers, etc.) will be sent here
            metadata_target => "http_poller_metadata"
          }
        }

        output {
          elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
          stdout { codec => rubydebug }
        }
```

I am receiving an error:

```
An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\logstash-7.1.0\logsta
        sh-7.1.0\data\.lock, :backtrace=>["sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOExce
        ption(sun/nio/fs/WindowsException.java:83)", "sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethro
        wAsIOException(sun/nio/fs/WindowsException.java:97)", "sun.nio.fs.WindowsException
```

Edit 1: post giving permissions to data folder suggested by @apt-get_install_skill , below is the timeout error i received:

```
    [0] "_http_request_failure"
    ],
    "http_request_failure" => {
                "request" => {
             "method" => "get",
                "url" => "https://nfr.saas.appdynamics.com/controller/rest/applications?output=JSON",
            "headers" => {
                "Accept" => "application/json"
            },
               "auth" => {
                 "user" => "readonly",
                 "pass" => "mypass@123",
                "eager" => true
            }
        },
        "runtime_seconds" => 10.004,
                   "name" => "test2",
                  "error" => "connect timed out",
              "backtrace" => nil
    }
}
```

Im new to APIs, and I'm not sure how to simply fetch the output from the URL. Could you help me on getting this corrected?
The URL works when i hit it on my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the elasticsearch output but more the permissions of the file

```
D:\logstash-7.1.0\logstash-7.1.0\data\.lock
```

as stated in the stacktrace:

error=>**java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\logstash-7.1.0\logstash-7.1.0\data\.lock**, :backtrace=>["sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOExce
    ption(sun/nio/fs/WindowsException.java:83)", "sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethro
    wAsIOException(sun/nio/fs/WindowsException.java:97)", "sun.nio.fs.WindowsException

You need to make sure that the user that executes logstash has the permissions to read and write this file.

Comment: I did manage to correct that thanks, but my API is anyway facing a connection timed out error. I have added the error as update in the question. @apt-get-install-skill,

Comment: Just did @apt-get_install_skill

Comment: Well it seems like that the machine logstash is running on can not connect to the specified URL within that 60 second period. Is there a firewall that blocks the request? Can you do a curl on that URL from the logstash instance?

Comment: This is a Windows machine so i tried running the URL in my browser and it works fine. There are only 2 json inputs on the URL. @apt-get_install_skill

Comment: Thats not the same. You need to check if you can reach the URL with the logstash user/service. You can download curl for windows on this page https://curl.haxx.se/windows/

Comment: It says, curl: (7) Failed to connect to nfr.saas.appdynamics.com port 443: Time
d out
@apt-get_install_skill

Comment: could you also please tell me why this is working in a browser and it is not the same with logstash? does my browser not use any system user or port?